# Contact is not deleting from MI mobile

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have made an contact application. I am able to delete contact from samsung and moto but in MI(XIOMI) unable to delete contact. It display popup with message "Contact can't delete by third party apps. My code

```
 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
 String[] args = new String[]{id};

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", args).build());
    try {
        contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Was the RawContact created on your app's Account using your SyncAdapter?

Anyway, try this:

```
Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
rawContactUri = rawContactUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(rawContactUri).build();
```

Comment: its not working. I have add account before adding contact:                                      ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());